# Нужно сравнить элементы в списке и вывести наибольшее значение

Tags: python, list

Код считает количество определенных символов ( **")", "(", "!", "."**), а затем относительно большего выводит "настроение" сообщения - Веселое, грустное, злое, задумчивое, нужно сделать пятую эмоцию - Неопределенность(когда совпадают какие то эмоции по одинаковому количеству, без понятия как сделать эмоцию неопределенности - Unclear)

Когда какой то из символов превосходит остальные, то выводит верно, но если есть одинаковые символы или все символы равны нулю, то выводит все "настроения", нужно сделать так, что бы при совпадении хотя бы двух выводил - Unclear

```
predlojenie = input("Введите предложение: ")

Funny = predlojenie.count(")")

Sad = predlojenie.count("(")

Angry = predlojenie.count("!")

Deep = predlojenie.count(".")

Variants = [Funny, Sad, Angry, Deep]

maximum = max(Variants)
if maximum == Funny:
    print("Funny")
if maximum == Sad:
    print("Sad")
if maximum == Angry:
    print("Angry")
if maximum == Deep:
    print("Deep")
```

Comment: так а в чем вопрос? Условные операторы и операторы сравнения вам известны. Применяйте.

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно модифицировать условия так. Обратите внимание на `elif` вместо остальных `if`:

```
maximum = max(Variants)
if Variants.count(maximum) > 1:
    print("Unclear")
elif maximum == Funny:
    print("Funny")
elif maximum == Sad:
    print("Sad")
elif maximum == Angry:
    print("Angry")
elif maximum == Deep:
    print("Deep")
```